# Content on 90% of my website looks to have disapeared

Tags: content

Website is [www.woodslabs.ca](http://www.woodslabs.ca).  I was having issues with an error appearing when trying to edit pages so I reached out to my hosting company for help.

After a few back and forth they were able to get rid of the issue saying it was a plugin issue with Advanced Custom Fields PRO plugin and they disabled it.

However now 90% of my website content is missing throughout several pages.  They look blank in WP.

I reached out to the hosting company but they seem to be having an issue fixing this. Anyone know what would have gone wrong here?

Here is my website before:
https://web.archive.org/web/20231101055104/https://woodslabs.ca/

Comment: Your content was probably added using that plugin. If that plugin was causing your site to have issues you’ll need to contact its author to help resolve those issues so that you can re-activate it. Third party plugin support is off topic here so you’ll need to go to the author.

Comment: You Can Deactivate Pro Plugin.May Site start working. Can you share error log last 20 lines. here

Comment: The plugin was deactivated and that's what caused the problem. Error log lines would be useful though yes.

Comment: What was the error you were getting? (Please edit it into the question) It sounds like your site depends on ACF so you'll need to turn it back on, so let's see if we can solve the original error instead maybe.

Comment: if you can identify the error from the PHP error log then the error can be fixed and ACF can be reactivated, bringing back all the content added via ACF fields that has dissapeared